# Loading Java.Util.Set in to Spring ConfigurationProperties

Tags: java, spring

Following Spring @ConfigurationProperties Class

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "prefix")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class config {
    private Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Following Yaml file

```
prefix:
  mySet: !!set {'element1',  'element2'}
```

Using SnakeYaml version 1.16

Results in the follow error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'messageDelivery[0]' of bean class
>   [location.Config]:
>   Property referenced in indexed property path 'mySet[0]' is
>   neither an array nor a List nor a Map; returned value was [element1]

Appears the error is occurring during serialization

**Update**

I tried with this yaml structure

```
prefix:
    mySet:
        element1
        element2
```

This resulted in a Set with only one value which is "element1 element2" it concatenated both together need to find out what will allow me to separate the the elements from each other

Comment: it might be the issue of declaration ? 
Not an Array set ['element1' , 'element2']
Not a List ["element1" , "element2" , "element3"]
Not a Map {'element1' : 'apple' , 'element2' : 'orange'} change declaration and try

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalHyder I have tried many different ways to express the data structure including the ones you mentioned but they resulted in the same ara

Comment: prefix="channel-broker" did you try with it? coz you are passing different prefix for Bean in this snippet @Marquis Blount

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalHyder sorry about that. That was just a bad copy and paste. both prefix match in my actual environment

Comment: prefix:
  mySet : 
         Marquis (next line)
         Blount (next line, remove these)
         Faisal

Comment: Component
 EnableConfigurationProperties
 ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "prefix") 
 try with order  let me know

Comment: did it work ? Marquis?

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalHyder its a step in the right direction finally able to create the Set only thing is that the elements where combined into one element so i have {element1 element2} instead of (element1, element2} notice the comma

Comment: So my comment helped you :D i should post answer ans you  can accept ?

Answer (score 5):

The Structure that I finally got working needed a comma added

```
prefix:
    mySet:
        element1,
        element2
```

Answer (score 2):

I see 2 problems in code you shared.

1. `mySet` is private, I'm wondering how Spring can load data into it
2. the YAML format is wrong, should be

```yaml
prefix:
   mySet:
     - element1
     - element2
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with:

```
prefix:
    ? element1
    ? element2
```

This should work in order to represent a set in yaml file. You can see the details here: https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/

Comment: I also tried adding the !!set tag after prefix that didnt work either